# Sending information IN Intent and using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: java, android

My application involves tracking of vehicle movement through check gates

[image]

When a person posted at the gate clicks the Pass button against a vehicle number, that vehicle should be removed from the list. I have done it by calling the VehicleActivity class again with putting the gate id in key-value pair.

```
Intent intentClear = new Intent(context, VehicleActivity.class);                    
intentClear.putExtra(VehicleActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, Integer.toString(gate_id));
context.startActivity(intentClear);
```

However if the user presses the back button, the previous list shows up which may confuse the user. To remove the previous screen I can use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, but then the information sent through putExtra gets removed.

Please suggest the best possible way of solving this as any problem in that list might make the vehicles stuck at checkgates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart your current activity, simply call `finish();` after `startActivity();`.

This will clear current activity after you start the new one and it doesn't exist in the back stack anymore.

Comment: I have used ((VehicleActivity) context).finish(). Still the key-value pair sent through the intent gets removed

Comment: I try your workflow from my end and it works fine, the intent param is there even when you finish the previous activity. We need some more code to investigate the issue. 

Something you should recheck that I see you `putExtra` as `String` (`Integer.toString(gate_id)`). Then you should retrieve it by `getStringExtra`, not `getIntExtra`

Comment: Thanks Tam. I had getIntExtra at other end. Copy pasting between files . I will accept your answer

Comment: Glad that I can help :D